# How to limit command to the server where the command was called?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I created a Discord bot which has some commands that generates riddels and riddels answers.

I discovered a bug that was triggered: if I invite the bot in two different servers and try to run one command in one of this two servers, it will run it in the second one and that's actually bad because I wanted each server to be independent. If the command is run on one server, it shouldn't be run on another.

I tried to save server id and tried to write some conditions with it but didn't work.

on the first server:
[image: server 1]

on the second server:
[image: server 2]

I want to make the command works per server not get shared in all of them

```js
let CommandRunned = CommandRunnedWithSpace.trim().toLowerCase()
let argsWithOutSpace = receivedMess.content.toLowerCase().slice(mentionNumber).trim().split(' ');
const cmd = argsWithOutSpace.shift().toLowerCase();
const args = argsWithOutSpace.join(' ');

if (CommandRunned === 'startriddle') {

    if (RiddleMap.get('check') === true) {
        receivedMess.reply("Riddle Already Started (can't start two riddels at the sametime)");
    } else {
        currentCluesArray = [];

        clueI = 0;

        getRndNum = (min, max) => {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        let randomNum = getRndNum(0, RiddlesApi.Riddles.length - 1)

        RiddlesApi.Riddles.filter((Riddel) => {

            if (Riddel.id === randomNum) {
                RiddleMessage = Riddel.Riddle
                answer = Riddel.Answer
                clues = Riddel.clues
            }
        })

        StartRiddleModuel.startRiddle(receivedMess, RiddleMessage);
        RiddleMap.set('check', true);
    }
}


if (cmd === 'answer') {
    if (answerCooldown.has(receivedMess.author.id)) {
        receivedMess.delete();
        receivedMess.reply('You have to wait ' + answercdseconds + ' seconds befor answering again')
    } else {
        if (RiddleMap.get('check') === true) {
            if (args === answer) {
                RiddleMap.set('check', false);
                receivedMess.reply("Correct :hushed: ")
                receivedMess.react('✅');
            } else if (args === '') {
                receivedMess.reply("Well you didnt enter anything.How you want me to know your answer then.")
                receivedMess.react('');
            } else {
                receivedMess.reply("That wasnt the right answer try again :smirk: ")
                receivedMess.react('❌');
            }
            answerCooldown.add(receivedMess.author.id);
        } else {
            receivedMess.reply("No Riddles did started");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there. I'm afraid it's hard to understand what the problem is based on the information you've given us. Perhaps take a little more time to structure the question and explain from the beginning if you can.

Comment: @Rillus Gona try to explain again here :P.I have created a bot in which it runs riddles thru cmds and a user in that spicific server can answer that riddle.testing the bot i tried to inv him in another server.So that said i found a bug in wich when i started a riddle it like started for the two servers and tecnicly i only wanted it to start for that specific server.Can you pls help me? :D

Comment: @Rillus I just edited the question.If you don't mind gonna be appreciated if you have any ideas how to fix my problem

Comment: Can you add your code? If we don't know what you tried, we can't help you. Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [make a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JackRed done ty for the infos.I am just new to this :P

Answer (score 1):

Without having complete code it's pretty hard to point out which lines of code should be changed. However, the general idea is to compare guild ID each time you run the command. Under `Message` object, you can find guild ID like this:

```js
msg.guild.id
```

When user requests a riddle, you should save the guild ID and then compare it with the ID from the answer command.

---

However, there's another solution which could better fit your needs: [`awaitMessages` method from TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) class.

The most important benefit is that it's used **per channel**, so you don't need to add any logic like the one I described above.

Example from documentation should help you to properly incorporate it in your script (comments and minor changes mine):

```js
// Here you need to create a filter to 'catch' only desired messages
// E.g. filter I use to check if my bot was pinged is as below
// message.mentions.users.some(mention => mention.id === client.user.id)
const filter = m => m.content.includes('answer');

// Here you specify max: 1 as you want to catch and respond to each message
channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
  .then(collected => console.log('If correct command was sent, program enters here'))
  .catch(collected => console.log('In case errors or timeout, put commands here'));
```

The only thing missing is to loop `awaitMessages` (so that it doesn't end after one message is found) and set separate timer so you know when the time for answering ends.